# Porting C# statement to C++

Tags: c#, c++

I would like to port this C# (Visual Studio) statement to C++98. Unable to use C++11 `copy_if`. Here is the C# code:

```
List<Node> nodes = tree.Nodes.FindAll(n => n.Leaf == false && n.Left == null && n.Right == null);
```

How do I port using `for_each` and `find_if`? 
I started with this line of code:

`find_if(tree->getNode().begin, tree->getNode().end, TopNode(tree->getNode()[index]));`

where `TopNode` is defined as:

```
struct TopNode
{
    explicit TopNode(Node *n) : MyNode(n) { }
    inline bool operator()(const Node *m) const { return ((m->getLeaf() == false && m->getLeft() == NULL && m->getRight() == NULL)); }

   private:
      Node *MyNode;
};
```

Can anyone help with writing this loop please? Thanks in advance for your time and suggestions.

Comment: Are you writing your own tree class?

Comment: Is this a prank or do you try to roll your own .Net Framework in C++?

Comment: @wp78de This is not a prank. The code is being ported to an embedded environment and there are no .Net Framework.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews No not trying to write my own tree class. Just need to learn how to write this one line of C# in C++.  As I understand it this C# code searches through the tree nodes, finds the one satisfying the predicate and stores them in a list and when done assigns it to the nodes list. This is really nice, and wish to know how to do a similar thing in C++. Appreciate any suggestions or guidance.

Comment: There is no generic tree class in C++.  So, you will need to write your own.